# "Text & Media" - Typo3 v8 - image with 0px width and height

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-8.7.x

The width and height of the image dose not apply in the html.

[image: Backend]

[image: Result in html]

How can I fix this?

Comment: - If you keep the width and height empty, is the output still 0?
- If you clear generated images in the install tool, does this change anything?
- Have you made any code changes to how the fluidtemplates are added in your template?
- Does disabling enlarge on click change anything?

Comment: I have installed the ext  Fluid Styled Content, and I've included  Fluid Styled Content into the template.  I have tried the options that you suggested, but without success..

Comment: Are you using both fluid_styled_content and css_styled_content? Does anything change when you remove css_styled_content?

Comment: I don't have css_styled_content.. it is not present in the list. Do you know why ?

Comment: I've installed "css_styled_content" ext, and now the width and the height are working. Interesting that it says "ext desprecated". What is he proper way to do this in Typo3 v8 ?

Comment: The proper way is to use fluid_styled_content to future proof your build. It's best to either use one or the other. If the width and height are working when you install css_styled_content but no use it. I'm not sure how that could possibly be related. But important thing is the bug is gone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the problem.

There was need for both Fluid Content Element and CSS to be included.

[image]

Thank you #Scopestyle for the ideas!